# ExtJS Grouping Grid sorting bug

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, extjs3, grid-layout

I have a grouping grid that groups by a field, lets say the group is 'team'. Then all the players in that team have a number and other fields such as name, contract start and end date.

Within the teams I can sort in alphabetical order by name of a player, and by dates as well. The sorting works on those fields.

The issue is when I try to sort by player number it sorts the following way.

Assume we have players 1 through 30.

The ascending order in my grid will be:

```
1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 21 etc.
```

Apparently for some reason it only compares the first digits but then between the teens it knows which ones come first (?).

I want the numbers sorted in a logical ascended order:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 20 21 22 ... 29 30
```

I am using ExtJS 3.3.1 grouping view in grid. The data for the grid store is coming from java objects and all the fields are strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings always sort this way in js. Try `"2" > "10"` in the console. You have to use a number type field on the model or the store. Like this:

```
fields: [
    {name: '...', type: 'int'}
]
```

When doing Array sort functions, use `parseInt(...)` to convert to numbers first.

Comment: Thanks, adding type int for the field in the store config worked. I forgot js compares the string numbers like this.